# Makefile clarification: files that includes headers which includes another header

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

What happens when my program includes a header that includes another header?
Say, for example, main.c includes header1.h, and header1.h includes header2.h. Should my makefile be:

```
main.x: main.o
    gcc -o main.x

main.o: main.c header1.h header2.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

OR is it unnecessary to include header2.h?

```
main.x: main.o
    gcc -o main.x

main.o: main.c header1.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

Or is it unnecessary to include any headers at all?

```
main.x: main.o
    gcc -o main.x

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c
```

Comment: Yes. All included headers, including those included transitively. Note gcc will determine dependencies for you with the `-M` (and similar related like `-MM`) option.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov hmmm, yea, but in this question, you see after one second what it's about, the other one you have to analyse a somewhat complex example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of listing *dependencies* in a Makefile is to let `make` know under what circumstances it needs to rebuild. If a file listed as a dependency has been modified since the target was built, the target needs to be rebuilt. So it's a good idea to list all files which are consulted in the coarse of building the target.

If you don't list an hour included file, then everything will still work -- until you edit the file you didn't tell `make` about, at which point you'll find that `make` might not bother to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to name every single include file as dependency, because (by design) make doesn't know anything about how C works. gcc and GNU make provide a solution for this:

```
main.x: main.o
    gcc -o main.x

main.o main.d: main.c
    gcc -MD -MF -MG -MP main.d -c main.c

-include main.d
```

The dash in front of `include` causes make to ignore missing `.d` files, `-MD` ... causes `gcc` to generate a file containing dependency rules for use in `make` (`-MD` causes the generation as a side effect of compilation, `-MF` names the file to write those to, `-MG` causes the creation of a rule that assumes, missing header files will be created and `-MP` creates phony targets for header files, so deleting a header file doesn't prevent further building because of missing dependencies).